# Is there music available for a c1780 square piano with 5 octaves F to F

Tags: piano

I am bringing a 1742 house back to its original state and furnishing. I would like to buy a piano as described above that I have found in an antique shop  but I would like to use it for entertainment at parties and etc. instead of just having it for looks.  Would there be sheet music available for a relative able pianist?

Comment: Up until about 1820, all pianos had five octaves. Harpsichords from before this period had about 4-1/2 octaves. Thus, virtually every piece of keyboard music written before about 1820 -- Mozart, Haydn, Schubert, Beethoven, Bach, Couperin, Scarlatti, etc. can be played on such an instrument.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Most music for piano is within 5 octaves and even if you find music that is outsize what I'm assuming is the range F2 - F6 you can transpose it  and rearrange the music as necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much. Obviously, I am not a piano player and find your answer very helpful

Comment: You have rather more than that available: most harpsichord and clavichord music is well within FF-f''' (that being the range of late-18th century harpsichords), and will probably suit your piano well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. While I am not a musician, I thought that maybe harpsichord music might work. I have even tried to find a harpsichord from that period.

Comment: Harpsichords from that period are a bit rare, and when in playable condition, _very_ pricey. I would suggest looking at modern instruments whose construction methods were based on original instruments. New, these are still very expensive, but there is a used market.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is music of that time available, virtually all of it is well in the public domain by now. imslp.org has more early piano music available than you can play in a lifetime of parties.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was most helpful.  I will see if i can browse imlp.org.